# Secure connection between Google App Engine Endpoints and mobile client (Android, iPhone)

Tags: android, ios, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm trying to send secure user data between iPhone and Android clients to a Google cloud endpoints backend. However, when I look at the network log, I can see the data unencrypted, despite the url of our app engine project being https. Is there anyway to securely send this data over a network, or do we have to encrypt it on the iphone and android and then decrypt it in our app engine project manually?

Answer (score 0):

Is this log part of the development stack, or an independent program like Wireshark? If it's the former, I believe the client libraries log the unencrypted data to ease debugging. Something like Wireshark should just show an HTTPS stream, and not plaintext.

Comment: It was part of the development stack. But the data sent over the network to appengine is encrypted using https?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Endpoints will only make requests over HTTPS.